# programmatically set colspan and rowspan for control in tablelayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net

I can not seem to figure out how to set colspan and rowspan programatically in vb.net
I have a tablelayoutpanel which I am programattically adding a label to I am able to add the label but I can not set the colspan and rowspan please help

```
    Dim lbl1 As Label = New Label()
    lbl1.AutoSize = False
    lbl1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl1.Text = newid
    lbl1.Height = 46
    lbl1.Width = 42
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl1, 1, 2) 'adds the label to column 1 row 1
```

I need to modify the colspan to 4 and rowspan to 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You set `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` like this:

```
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(lbl1, 4)
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(lbl1, 2)
```